# How to perform one hot encoding in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

Hi I've been trying to do this for the past few hours but I just can't seem to get it to work. I have imported the necessary packages and assigned my csv file to a variable X.

My csv file is one column with numbers ranging from 0 to 9 for each element. I would like to create another csv file with 10 columns with 0s and 1s to use as a target set. I've tried using sklearns labelencoder and onehotencoder but I haven't had any luck.

Thanks for reading and for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you share the code you were using and your input data? `OneHotEncoder` should work out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's in a csv file, you can use Pandas package in the following way

```
import pandas as pd            #importing the package        
df = pd.read_csv(path)         #df is a variable containing the data-frame of the csv file
ydf = pd.get_dummies(df['label']) #'label' is the title of the the column
                                  #in the csv you want to one hot encode
```

check the [pandas dummy documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

If it's a numpy array you can try the following way

```
import numpy as np
vector = np.arange(5)    # vector = [0 1 2 3 4]

one_hot = (vector == 0).astype(np.int)  #[1 0 0 0 0]
one_hot = (vector == 2).astype(np.int)  #[0 0 1 0 0]
one_hot = (vector == 4).astype(np.int)  #[0 0 0 0 1]
```

so you can do that with your numpy array

```
vector = np.arange(no_of_different_labels)

# transform labels into one hot representation
y_train_one_hot = (vector == y_train).astype(np.float)
# make sure you y_train is of size (m,1) and not (m,) for broadcasting to work
```

got it from this [link](https://www.python-course.eu/neural_network_mnist.php)

Comment: Not too sure how to private message on here you so i'll just comment here. The pandas method helped me out a lot and I've been able to use it as a targer set. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: you're welcome, glad to be of help